# Fade In animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I'm working on this website http://1ne-studio.com/test2/

id : test　 pass : 2015

I have parallax site where elements on 3-5th slides have fade-In effect controlled by javascript(scrollinTurn.js
).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.element').scrollInTurn();
});
```

However, this fade-in effect won't show up and I can't see the slides.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the code?

Comment: check if that element was hidden..

Comment: Yes I have uncommented the code. Still can't see those elements...

Comment: @DyrandzFamador Thanks I looked at it is not hidden...

Answer (score 0):

Try this at bottom of stylesheet

```
#slide-3,#slide-5 {opacity:0!important}
body.active-slide-3 #slide-3,
body.active-slide-5 #slide-5 {opacity:1!important}
```

Comment: `.active-slide .storyBk,
.active-slide .storyInner,
.active-slide .blurbBk,
.active-slide .blurbInner,
.active-slide .charaImg01,
.active-slide .charaTitle01,
.active-slide .charaTxt01,
.active-slide .charaImg02,
.active-slide .charaTitle02,
.active-slide .charaTxt02,
.active-slide .charaImg03,
.active-slide .charaTitle03,
.active-slide .charaTxt03{
opacity: 1 !important;}`

Thanks! I added few css like this to solve the issue!

However, when I look at it in Firefox, all the layout is collapsed and they all the layers are show in one place...